# select2 validation not empty value send

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have `select2` jquery plugin and i set it to multiple  select option and i want to required this field if not any option select then not `submit` the form and give the message this field is required. why when field is empty and i click on `submit button` and `alert` not show. any helps.
code

```js
jQuery(function($){


  $('#example').select2({
      placeholder: 'Select a month'
  });

    $(".add").click(function(e){

    if (jQuery('#example').val() == '') {
      alert('this feilds is required');
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>


<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>

<div>
<button class="add">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you not just add the required tag to the select?

Comment: Replace with `alert(jQuery('#example').val())` and you'll see why

Answer (score 3):

You are checking for `''` which is a string space i believe where as `#example` give `null` as a default value.

Just check for `null`.

```js
jQuery(function($){


  $('#example').select2({
      placeholder: 'Select a month'
  });

    $(".add").click(function(e){

    if (jQuery('#example').val() == null) {
      alert('this feilds is required');
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>


<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>

<div>
<button class="add">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @likorendell than accept the answer Happy to help,  :)